# Having trouble building a regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that has the following rules:

- it must start with a character or an asterisk
- a character can be followed by more characters, a full stop or the equals sign
- a full stop must be followed by more characters or an asterisk
- an asterisk must be followed by the equals sign

Legitimate cases would be:

- *=text
- word=text
- word.word.word...word=text    (ie. There can be many repititions of .word)
- word.*=test

If this needs more clarification just let me know, it's kind of hard to explain it.

I currently have this for my regular expression:

```
(\w+\.)*(\*|\w+)\=\w+
```

Which correctly validates the given examples, however it matches ".*=INFO" which should be invalid. Anyone know how I can get it to not match this string?

Comment: Please specify which regex engine this is being used and tested against. (That it's one that supports `\w` points to PCRE, but a solid answer would be better than a guess -- there are several engines with varying syntax inspired by PCRE).

Comment: To be clear, in the `word.word.word...word=text` form, is it mandatory that the words be identical? That is, is `foo.bar.baz=text` also valid, or only `foo.foo.foo=text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\*|\w+(\.\w+)*(\.\*)?)\=\w+$
```

This handles separately cases which start with an asterisk and those which start with a character, since I wasn't able to combine them.

```
^          begin
(
 \*        asterisk
|            or
 \w+       first word
 (\.\w+)*  optionally more words, separated by dot
 (\.\*)?   optional dot + asterisk
)
\=         equals
\w+
$          end
```

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let's call an asterisk or a word of any non-zero length a token. So, `word` and `*` are "tokens".
We can describe it using regular expression as `(\*|\w+)`.

Now, we want regex which matches the following:

- begining of a line
- a token
- 0 or more combinations of (dot + token)
- equals sign and a non-empty word
- end of a line

As result, we have something like

```
^(\*|\w+)(\.(\*|\w+))*=\w+$
```

which is

```
^         (\*|\w+)       (\.(\*|\w+))*               =\w+$   
begin     token          0 or more (dot + token)     equals, word and end
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR9uD6/2)

Comment: This came very close to working but unfortunately it let you have multiple asterisks.